# How do I print a distinct response to the first try as opposed to the following five guesses? (Noob level number guessing game)

Tags: python

Just starting out here and was hoping someone could help me with an issue I'm having. Haven't been able to find any clear answers online, likely because this is such an early level exercise.

Basically I want to have the program print a different response after the first incorrect answer. For example... the first prompt is "Take a guess!" but after that I would like it to say... "Take another guess!"

Could anyone shed some light on this for me? Thanks in advance.

```
# Number guessing game.
import random
from time import sleep
secretNumber = random.randint(1, 20)
print('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 20. You have five chances to guess correctly.')
sleep(1)

# Ask the player to guess six times. 
for guessesTaken in range(1, 6):
    print('Take a guess!')
    if guessesTaken > 1:
        print('Take another guess!')
    guess = int(input())
    
    
    if guess < secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too low.')
    elif guess > secretNumber:
        print('Your guess is too high.')
    else:
        break #this is the correct guess!

if guess == secretNumber:
    print('Good job! You guessed my number in ' + str(guessesTaken) + ' guesses!')
else:
    print('Nope. The number I was thinking of was ' + str(secretNumber) + '.')
```

Comment: I'm sure someone will give you the "ready to copy and paste" answer, but if you just want hints, you have think about when that has to happen. So, how do you know if it's the first attempt or not? You need a variable to keep track of that. I see you know how to assign variables and how to use `if` so you can probably figure it out from there

Comment: A really simple way would just be adding another if statement to check what iteration you are on. So if guessesTaken > 1, then you must be on the second guess or more, in which case you want to ask the player to "Take another guess!"

Comment: I have updated the code, and feel like I understand what should be happening. The new statement is printing correctly. However...I cannot seem to stop the original "Take a guess!" printing with every loop.

Comment: Thanks Stuart! That worked. Although I had to change one thing. 

if (user := int(input('Take a guess: ' if guess == 1 else 'Try again: ' ))) == computer:

Having it set as zero wasn't working, but changing it to 1 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using *print* to show the prompt, add it to the *input* function call. Within that you can use a ternary-style expression. Here's an example:

```
import random

NGUESSES = 6
RANGE = 1, 20

computer = random.randint(*RANGE)

for guess in range(NGUESSES):
    if (user := int(input('Take a guess: ' if guess == 0 else 'Try again: '))) == computer:
        print(f'Good job! You guessed correctly in {guess+1} guesses')
        break
    print('Too low' if user < computer else 'Too high')
else:
    print(f'Nope. The number I was thinking of was {computer}')
```